# Не приходит SMS-подтверждение при регистрации по номеру телефона

Tags: java, android, firebase, авторизация, sms

Не приходит SMS-подтверждение при регистрации по номеру телефона  по мануалам от Google и примерам из интернета. По тестовым номерам вход производится. Название пакета и SHA-1 что в среде Android Studio и в консоли Firebase идентичны, но приложение говорит, что надо проверить их корректность. App validation failed. 
Есть у кого опыт реализации авторизации через СМС-сервисы, SMS.RU, SMSC.RU?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - использовать Account Kit от [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/). Плюс ведение некой аналитики очень наглядно. Все легко настраивается по мануалу.